# ASP.NET MVC Mock/initialize sessionID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

we have a code below on service layer to get sessionID and pass to external API for session correlation.

```
public static string GetCorrelationSession()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        //do some check and 
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated | userContext == null)
                return HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    }
    else
    { 
        return null
    }
}
```

I tried and also googled how we can mock the httpcontext.current.session.sessionID but all examples seems to be asp.net controller.

What's the best way to mock or initiaze httpcontext.current.session.sessionID  on unit test?

Comment: Do you use Dependency Injection?

Comment: Yes we use autofac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always avoid using static method like you're doing because it is difficult to mock them. You need to make an abstract of how you get the session ID. You can create an abstraction that will give the current session Id like below:

```
public interface ISessionProvider 
{
    string GetCorrelationSession();
}
```

then have an implementation `AspNetSessionProvider` that will look like this:

```
public interface AspNetSessionProvider : ISessionProvider
{
    public string GetCorrelationSession()
    {
        // Here you put how to get the current session Id.
    }
}
```

So how to use it? You can use one of the following solutions:

#### Dependency injection:

If you are using dependency injection then inject the `ISessionProvider` in every controller or service where you need it via their contrcutor. Because it is not difficult to mock an interface then all your classes that use this interface can be tested very easy.

#### Ambient context with default implementation:

Use this solution only if so many services or controllers need to access to the `ISessionProvider` so it becomes cross-cutting provider. It is like Property Injection (Dependency Injection) but with default implementation if not set. So you create another new class let's name it `SessionProvider` so its code look like this:

```
public class SessionProvider
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ISessionProvider> InstanceProvider = new Lazy<ISessionProvider>(() => GetSessionProviderFromFactory() ?? new AspNetSessionProvider());

    private static Func<ISessionProvider> _factory;

    public static ISessionProvider Instance
    {
        get { return InstanceProvider.Value; }
    }

    public static void SetSessionProvider(Func<ISessionProvider> sessionProviderFactory)
    {
        if (_factory != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The session provider factory is already initialized");
        }
        if (sessionProviderFactory == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The session provider factory value can't be null");
        }

        _factory = sessionProviderFactory;
    }

    private static ISessionProvider GetSessionProviderFromFactory()
    {
        ISessionProvider sessionProvider = null;
        if (_factory != null)
        {
            sessionProvider = _factory();
            if (sessionProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The session factory, when it is set, must not return a null isntance.");
            }
        }

        return sessionProvider;
    }
}
```

In your application code you use it by calling this line whenever you need to access the session Id:

```
SessionProvider.Instance.GetCorrelationSession();
```

In your test fixture setup of your unit tests, you can set the mocked instance by using this code :

```
var mock = new Mock<ISessionProvider>(); 
// Setup the mock 
SessionProvider.SetSessionProvider(() => mock.Object);
```